# Generating API layer using OpenApi generator in a multi module Maven project

Tags: java, maven, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Hello Maven community,

I have a multi module Maven project (for my Spring Boot application) for which I would like to generate API layer using [OpenAPI generator - Maven plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin).

Let me explain the structure and at the end you can see a link to a repo with project.

I have basically three `pom.xml`. First pom is on the project level, it has `<dependencyManagement>` from where other modules inherit dependencies and specify other versions as the see fit. Second pom is within module `company-gaming-rest-api`, idea with this module is that it doesn't contain any source code, only yaml file(s) for generating API layer along with some DTOs. Finally, second pom.xml comes from a module called `company-gaming-service-core`. Idea with this module is to actually contains bussiness logic and have  under its `/target` folder all those generated APIs.

So in `company-gaming-service-core` pom.xml I have used plugin like so:

```
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>gaming-generation</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/target/company/gaming/game.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>company.gaming.ms.game.controller</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>company.gaming.ms.game.model</modelPackage>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <configOptions>

                                <enableBuilderSupport>true</enableBuilderSupport>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <dateLibrary>java11</dateLibrary>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                                <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                                <simpleFluentPattern>true</simpleFluentPattern>
                                <collectionFluentPattern>true</collectionFluentPattern>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Entire project is using only two libraries, `mapstruct` and `lombok`, since in my humble understanding they are needed for api generator to generate classes/methods for API layer.

I'm using IntelliJ, so here is the image of a clean project:

[image: Clean project]

Here is the structure of project after `mvn clean install -DskipTests`:

[image]

The error, after `mvn clean install -DskipTests`, I'm getting is very strange:

```
[INFO] Configured Artifact: company.gaming.ms:company-gaming-rest-api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:jar
[INFO] Unpacking C:\Users\FirstName.Lastname\Desktop\company-gaming-service\company-gaming-rest-api\target\company-gaming-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\FirstName.Lastname\Desktop\company-gaming-service\company-gaming-service-core\target with includes "**/*.yaml" and excludes ""
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- openapi-generator-maven-plugin:4.0.2:generate (company-gaming) @ company-gaming-service-core ---
[WARNING] Exception while reading:
java.lang.RuntimeException: **Could not find C:/Users/FirstName.Lastname/Desktop/company-gaming-service/company-gaming-service-core/target/company/gaming/game.yaml on the classpath**
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.ClasspathHelper.loadFileFromClasspath (ClasspathHelper.java:31)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readWithInfo (OpenAPIV3Parser.java:135)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readLocation (OpenAPIV3Parser.java:45)
    at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation (OpenAPIParser.java:16)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput (CodegenConfigurator.java:586)
```

It says it cannot find on the classpath but it managed to copy it from rest module to core module. I did play with other versions of mapstruct/openapi plugin, but no luck :(

Here is the [link to the repo](https://github.com/Coding-Hefestus/company-gaming-service)

Yaml schema is correct and validate against [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/).

**Update1**
Based on the suggestion from khmarbaise:

I have commented out in core-module plugin related to api generator. Now, in my rest-api module I have following:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>company.gaming.ms</groupId>
                                <artifactId>company-gaming-rest-api</artifactId>
                                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <includes>**/*.yaml</includes>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>


        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>company-gaming-api-generation</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

                        <!--${project.basedir}

                        C:/Users/FirstName.LastName/Desktop/repo/company-gaming-service/company-gaming-rest-api/src/main/resources/company.gaming/game.yaml-->
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}\src\main\resource\company\gaming\game.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <apiPackage>company.gaming.ms.game.controller</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>company.gaming.ms.game.model</modelPackage>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <configOptions>

                            <enableBuilderSupport>true</enableBuilderSupport>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <dateLibrary>java11</dateLibrary>
                            <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                            <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                            <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                            <simpleFluentPattern>true</simpleFluentPattern>
                            <collectionFluentPattern>true</collectionFluentPattern>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-client-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi/src/main/java</source>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc-client</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
```

Tried with `/` `\` `company.gaming` `company/gaming` its just keep serving me with:

```
[INFO] --- openapi-generator-maven-plugin:6.6.0:generate (gaming-api-generation) @ company-gaming-service-core ---
[WARNING] Exception while reading:
io.swagger.v3.parser.exception.ReadContentException: Unable to read location `main/company-gaming-rest-api/src/main/resources/company.gaming/game.yml`
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readContentFromLocation (OpenAPIV3Parser.java:295)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readLocation (OpenAPIV3Parser.java:92)
```

Note that in error it outputs `.yml` instead of `.yaml`

Comment: First you should use a more recent version of the openapi-generator-maven-plugin.. (6.X+ see https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.openapitools/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/6.6.0/versions) ... use `main/company-gaming-rest-api/src/main/resources/company.gaming/game.yml` as source and do not change the output directory and do not use the `src/` directory... also your structure looks weird... and why do you have the generation within your application module instead of in your api module (meaning the execution of the openapi generator plugin) ? Does not make sense...

Comment: BTW: Why using Spring Boot 2.7.X instead 3.1+ and JDK 17 so that would result in avoiding the usage of lombok...

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, thanks for looking it up and thanks for your time. I need to use spring boot 2.7. since we have some other libraries that don't go well with higher versions of boot. Also our project is Java 11, this is just demo that I need to make it work. I bumped version to 6.6.0 also, in the `<inputSpec>` I tried placing: `main/company-gaming-rest-api/src/main/resources/company.gaming/game.yml`  and  `company-gaming-rest-api/src/main/resources/company.gaming/game.yml` both failed with same error.  Didn't understand your point on not using `src/`

Comment: And your last point, how to setup code so that it can generate classes/api layer in `company-gaming-rest-api` ? that could also work, tho, my requriments are that it needs to be generated in `company-gaming-service-core` Thank you for helping out

Comment: The requiements to generate the code in the service core means you have to move the yaml file into the same module and do so..otherwise it does not make sense.. I strongly recommend to have a separate module (api) and generate the code there ... and to use the generated code simply define a dependency in other module on that api module... that's clean and easy...

Comment: Hint about 2.7... means you have to upgrade as soon as possible because support for 2.7.X line is end of life in November this year (See https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support). The only way is to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.1+ and JDK17...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you once more for suggestions for spring boot version, will make sure to discuss with the team. I have updated my question and decided to accept you suggestion to generate api in rest-api module, but it isnot clean and easy to do so :) at least not for me. I have no idea what's wrong...

Comment: I've created a pull request for your repository and cleaned up the whole stuff...I don't understood why the dependeny plugin is needed and the configuration for m2e etc. ... that's unclear for me...Also I don't understand the need for build-helper-maven-plugin etc.

Answer (score 1):

Then **Open API maven generator plugin** runs before the classes (and resources) are compiled into `target` folder because it must generate the classes by the YAML which you referenced by your own project classes, so this is why it cannot find the YAML file into the target folder.

To solve this you have to change:
`<inputSpec>${project.basedir}/target/company/gaming/game.yaml</inputSpec>`

into

`<inputSpec>${project.basedir}/company-gaming-service/src/main/resources/company/gaming/game.yaml</inputSpec>`.

Comment: Hi Antonio, thanks for looking it up, but error is still the same. Have you managed to try on your machine? Maybe is something on my Windows/InteliJ setting?

Comment: I use this tecnique everyday. Maybe some other little error on your code, but unfortnately I cannot assit you so much. Sorry. :(